# How to determine if this converges?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, divergent-series, trigonometric-series, absolute-convergence

I find this one to be hard, I tried expanding $\cos$ into a Taylor series, but that didn't work out well because I couldn't apply  $p$-series...
$$
\sum^{\infty}_{n=1} n (1-\cos(\pi/n)) 
$$

Comment: Try limit comparison test with $\frac{1}{n}$.

Answer (score 1):

We know that $$1-\cos(\frac{\pi}{n})=2\sin^2(\frac{\pi}{n})$$ also $$\sin^2(\frac{\pi}{n}) \sim (\frac{\pi}{n})^2,  \ \  \ \ \text{as} \ \ \ n\to \infty$$ therefore $$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}n(1-\cos(\frac{\pi}{n}))=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}2n\sin^2(\frac{\pi}{n})\sim \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}2n (\frac{\pi}{n})^2=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} 2\frac{\pi^2}{n}$$. We know the series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\pi^2}{n}$ diverges , So this series   $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}n(1-\cos(\frac{\pi}{n}))$ will also diverge.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

Use the inequality $1-\cos x\ge \frac{x^2}{3}$ for $-2\le x\le 2.$

Comment: Yea but im misding something because when I do that the result tricks me. I get $\suma_n<(\pi^2/2)\sum (1/n)$... but it doesnt help for the bigger series to converge

Comment: I have realized I have used a non useful inequality. I have modified my answer.